# When to use Web Server (Oracle HTTP Server) in front of Weblogic

Tags: oracle, apache, https, weblogic

At work there is a legacy system on which a HTTP server (ohs) is used in front of an Oracle Weblogic Server for forwarding SSL connections.

Since Weblogic allows SSL connections to the web service, why/when is a Web Server needed in front of Weblogic; apart from the load-balance scenario?

Comment: This is likely a question that would be better suited for a different stack.  Load balancing and security would come to mind depending on your network topology.  Of course, there could also be some extension that the OHS server is using which the legacy application depends on that no one wants to invest the time to replicate over on WebLogic.